# How to find a bug in a nested for loop? Debug tips?

Tags: java, arrays, string, boolean

I am trying to create a simple TicTacToe game but I am having trouble having the program recognize a row of x's.

If you look at the following line of code:

```
public void run() {
    setFont("Helvetica-40");
    fillArray();
    checkWinner();
    run();
}

//fill array:
public void fillArray() {
    for(int row = 0; row<3; row++) {
        String fill = readLine("");
        for(int col=0; col<3;col++) {
            char xo = fill.charAt(row);
            String xoString = Character.toString(xo);
            ticTac[row][col] = xoString;
        }
    }
}

public boolean checkWinner() {
    // array[row][col]
    if (ticTac[0][0].equals("x") &&  ticTac[0][1].equals("x") && ticTac[0][2].equals("x")) {
        println("Player X wins!");
        return true;
    } else
        println("no x");
    return false;
}

String[][] ticTac = new String[3][3]; 

}
```

Comment: You will make it easier for people to help you if you indent your code properly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not storing the input properly, share the method `readLine` as well

Comment: Why `char xo = fill.charAt(row);` I have a feeling you want to do `char xo = fill.charAt(col);` there instead?

Comment: @Nicholas K readLine is imported from the Stanford library. I do not have access to its code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a mistake, you have to change one of these two things :

1.

```
if (ticTac[0][0].equals("x") &&  ticTac[0][1].equals("x") && ticTac[0][2].equals("x"))
```

to

```
if( ticTac[0][0].equals("x") &&  ticTac[1][0].equals("x") && ticTac[2][0].equals("x"))
```

or
2.

```
char xo = fill.charAt(row);
```

to

```
char xo = fill.charAt(col);
```

just one of them, it depend on your design

Comment: Yes, changing row to col did the trick. I left the if statement as is.